# Is there a way to redirect X command output to SAS variable dataset?

Tags: unix, sas

I have a SAS data step which has X command to grep a certain string in an external file (a.txt) then I want to redirect the output of the grep command to one of SAS dataset variable. Is that possible?

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INFILE PIPE and read the output from the UNIX command using the INPUT statement.  Consult the SAS documentation for details.

Comment: Thank you, data_null_! I never thought there's already a procedure for this. :)